# Sample Apps (ElizaChat and RecipeAssistant) doesn't open in Wear Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, wear-os

I'm trying to install ElizaChat and RecipeAssistant. They are successfully installed on my genymotion emulator. But not shown any notification on wear emulator. What is the reason for this issue and what is the solution?
I'm new to android wear development and I don't have an actual devices.

Also the inbuilt Speech Recorder App doesn't work on wear emulator?

Thank you in Advance

There are the steps I followed

1. Installed Android Studio
2. Created new AVD for wear
3. Pair Wear Emulator and Genymotion Emulator using below command
   \path\to\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s [device name Nexus 4] forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
4. Open the ElizaChat Sample app on Android Studio and Run
   This is how look like
   [image]
5. Open the RecipeAssistant Sample app on Android Studio and Run and Click start button on upper right corner and this is hoe look like
   [image]

Two Emulators are connected properly
[image]

LogCat of ElizaChat

```
08-22 13:35:52.372    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat D/dalvikvm﹕       GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 51K, 7% free 2731K/2936K, paused 60ms, total 64ms
08-22 13:35:52.400    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat I/dalvikvm-heap﹕     Grow heap (frag case) to 3.885MB for 1127532-byte allocation
08-22 13:35:52.408    2671-2680/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3830K/4040K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
08-22 13:35:52.512    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13K, 5% free 3870K/4040K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
08-22 13:35:52.512    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 5.294MB for 1440012-byte allocation
08-22 13:35:52.516    2671-2680/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 5276K/5448K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
08-22 13:35:53.144    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-22 13:35:53.164    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
08-22 13:35:53.164    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8c5c650, tid 2671
08-22 13:35:53.200    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
08-22 13:35:53.200    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
08-22 13:35:53.292    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-22 13:35:53.292    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
08-22 13:35:53.300    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
08-22 13:35:53.300    2671-2671/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-22 13:36:27.088    2688-2688/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat D/dalvikvm﹕  GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 50K, 8% free 2509K/2708K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
08-22 13:36:27.092    2688-2688/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.966MB for 1440012-byte allocation
08-22 13:36:27.092    2688-2697/com.example.android.wearable.elizachat D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3915K/4116K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
```

Comment: Are there any one who can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Running the Android Wear companion app in an emulator is not a supported configuration, and since the companion app is designed to run on a phone, it might be that you have not configured it properly. So there are many reasons why this might not be working.

Comment: Thank you @Wayne Piekarski for commenting. then how to connect android wear emulator and phone emulator properly and send notifications.

Comment: The only supported configurations for emulation are using a real Android device paired up with an Android Wear emulator running on your PC. There is documentation available here on how to do this: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#SetupEmulator